# How could I write debuglog in non jailbroken ios devices in C++?

Tags: c++, ios, logging

I want to write debug logs in non-jailbroken ios devices using C++. I have done same thing for Jail broken devices which works successfully. But I couldn't write the logs for non-jail broken devices. Is there a way to do this. I mean is it possible? if yes how?, if no why?

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "debug logs"? You can log things with `NSLog`.

Comment: Actually we are using a library developed in C++. Which writes log file for tracking transactions. The log file is successfully written in other platforms and jail broken ios devices. But it doesn't work in non jail broken ios devices.

Comment: where is the log file location? maybe you just need to move it into sandbox

Comment: I am saving the file in root location. How I can move it to sandbox? Will you provide me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Just need to grab the application's documents directory by following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
```

and after grabbing the path just need to write file in the directory saved in *basePath* returned by the above code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understand is that you are facing some problems in creating the file in the documents directory. I guess you are using fopen() or other C++ library functions to create the file. And you need the file path as char*. I think you need to do the following code to convert the path in char*.

```
NSString *myFilePath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.txt"];
const char *cPath = [basePath UTF8String];
char* filePath = (char*)cPath;
```

Above code should work. This code has worked for me.